# How to stop drop down menu elements overlapping?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to create a smooth drop down menu on mouse click

This is the exact effect I am looking for https://jsfiddle.net/j2fygbzb/13/

However I am looking for a way to prevent the drop down text elements from overlapping each other on the way down and up

JS

```
//toggleProjects
var toggleProjects = function() {

  //function
  var projectsList = document.getElementsByClassName('projects');
  // if(projectsList[0].style.display=='none'){
  if (!projectsList[0].classList.contains('projectsClass')) {
    //reappear
    for (var i = 0; i < projectsList.length; i++) {
      // projectsList[i].style.display='';
      projectsList[i].classList.add('projectsClass');
    }

  } else {
    //disappear
    for (var i = 0; i < projectsList.length; i++) {
      // projectsList[i].style.display='none';
      projectsList[i].classList.remove('projectsClass');
    }

  }
};

//event listener for click
document.getElementById('toggleTitle')
           .addEventListener('click', toggleProjects);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you for your time

Comment: Are you looking for a "sliding" effect?

Comment: Yes, a sliding transition just without the text elements overlapping as they slide into place; so rather appearing one by one

Comment: Cool! There are couples ways you could accomplish this. Some will require a bit more changes to your current markup than others (especially depending on the style of animation). Here's a super simple example (or concept) I threw together using CSS transition with height/overflow: https://jsfiddle.net/8eucmgs6/

Comment: You can apply the class to the actual menu, and use transition on height, rather than individual elements <li>
example: https://jsfiddle.net/j2fygbzb/65/

Comment: @Jack that is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @Jack I am coming up with the error 'Parsing error: Unexpected token state' do you know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `Parser error: Unexpected token state` you mentioned in the comments, that may be related to the code (the token error may be due to ES6 and your browser). To remove any doubt, here's a version of the code written in a more browser-friendly (and cleaner) way:

```
// IIFE to avoid exposing global variables
(function () {
    // Our "static" variables
    // These won't change in our event handler:

    // Variable to store our toggle "state" - whether it's open or closed
    var state = 0;

    // Element which we expand/collapse
    var menu = document.querySelector('ul');
    var total = menu.children.length;

    // 1.2 is a relative unit (rem).
    // If font-size is modified, you'll need to tweak this value
    var expandedHeight = 1.2 * total;
    var collapsedHeight = 1.2;

    function toggleProjects () {
        menu.style.height = (state ? expandedHeight : collapsedHeight) + 'rem';

        // Flip the state variable between 1 and 0
        state ^= 1;
    }

    document.body.querySelector('#toggleTitle').addEventListener('click', toggleProjects);
}());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rxLf8t3h/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer however this is coming up with 'document is not defined' error. How do I fix that?

Comment: @glittergirl, I've updated my answer! (`document.body` now) - I'm curious, which browser are you using/testing?

Comment: I'm using google chrome, It's still coming up with the same error (it works perfectly in html script tags which is super confusing to me)